Lenovo G480 with 24.04 lts bluetooth doesn't work
On a Lenovo G480 notebook with 8 Gb of RAM I installed Ubuntu LTS 20.04 and then updated to 22.04 LTS and finally to 24.04 LTS but with this latest version bluetooth doesn't work.
I wanted to add that after checking that it didn't work I booted the machine with a USB flash drive with Ubuntu 20.04 and bluetooth DID work.
I'm open to suggestions.
Thanks!

Can you append the result of the following command to your question 'sudo lshw -C' network

Please edit the question to include results from terminal for lsusb; sudo dmesg |egrep -i 'blue|firm'
